# Ignore strings after character if character found

Tags: java, regex

I need to have regex which finds the child and parent. For example:

> -->2014-05-21 22:05:23.092 INFO  [Core] org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader@692578be parents: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3, sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@65459c6f

The child is `org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader@692578be` and its parent is `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3`. The later string after `,` is ignored.

> -->2014-05-21 22:04:34.118 INFO  [Core] sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3 parent:
>   sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@65459c6f

In above the child is `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3` and the parent is `sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@65459c6f`

I have this regular expression `.* (.*) parents?: (.*),?.*`. It works with the second example. But for the first one outputs parent as:

> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3,
>   sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@65459c6f

but instead it should: `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is greedy by default, you should tell it to exclude `,`:

```
.* (.*) parents?: ([^,]*),?.*
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex:

```
(\S+) parents?: ([^,]+)
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dX8aT5)

Comment: Your code works, but I would prefer @Uri Agassi code

Comment: As far as possible I would avoid use of inefficient `.*` in my regex which backtracks heavily.